# Changing the style of a label in a Task thread

Tags: java, javafx

I wanted to change the style of a label in a task thread.
But it didn't work.
                                                    
Here is my code:

```
private Task getValidationTask() {
    return new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            String username = usernameField.getText();
            String password = passwordField.getText();
            if (!loginManager.exceededLimit()) {
                if (!loginManager.emptyForms(username, password)) {
                    updateMessage("Logging in ...");
                    status.setStyle("-fx-background-color: F0F0F0");
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace the line

```
status.setStyle("-fx-background-color: F0F0F0");
```

with:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                     @Override public void run() {
                         status.setStyle("-fx-background-color: F0F0F0");
                     }
                 });
```

This will execute the setStyle method in the main application thread and not in your  task's thread.